# Integration Integrate $\int_{-\theta c}^{\theta c} e^{-K/\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I'm trying to integrate $\displaystyle\int_{-\theta c}^{\theta c} e^{-K/\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta$

Numericaly the integrale look like clean, I try various method to have analytic form:

- Mathematica
- Taylor series

I wasn't able to find something.
For details:

- $0\lt\theta c\le\frac{\pi}{2}$
- $0\lt K\lt \infty$

Have you any guess about this form?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given: 
$$I = \displaystyle\int_{-\theta c}^{\theta c} e^{-K/\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta$$
* $0\lt\theta c\le\frac{\pi}{2}$, $0\lt K\lt \infty$

Then:
\begin{align}
I &= 2 \, \int_{0}^{\theta_{c}} e^{-K/\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta \\
&= 2 \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-K)^{n}}{n!} \, \int_{0}^{\theta_{c}} sec^{n}\theta \, d\theta \\
&= 2 \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-K)^{n}}{n!} \, \sin\theta_{c} \, {}_{2}F_{1}\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{n+1}{2}; \frac{3}{2}; \sin^{2}\theta_{c} \right). \\
\end{align}

Comment: What is F1?
And what represent the the indice before F1?
PS: I'm looking for finite form if its possible

Comment: Of course its equivalent to:
2$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\theta c} e^{-K/\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta$

If you have any guess or clue, I'll be happy to see them.